# Broken RMVB file not allows to use progress bar in "Movie Player" 

Tags: 10.10, codecs, video-player, totem, gstreamer

I am able to open broken RMVB file in "Movie Player", but I'm not able to use progress bar (eg. to skip intro of movie or jump to specific scene etc).
I would like to avoid installing mplayer.

Is there a quick way to install better codecs for RMVB format for "Movie Player"?

[I have noted that "Movie Player" allow not allow to use progress bar only for broken RMVB files]

Comment: may possibly be of assistance: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed "OggConvert" (via Ubuntu Software Center) and started converting rmvb to ogg format. Process has not finished yet, but I'm able to use progress bar in ogg format.

btw OggConvert will not list rmvb files by the default, choose "All Files".